# Django & timezone, beginning of the day : should I make_aware() in my function one or two times?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I have a simple function that returns the beginning of the day in Django (by default, today's day) :

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

def DayBeginning(DateTime="Now"):
    if DateTime == "Now":
        DateTime = make_aware(datetime.datetime.today())
    year = DateTime.year
    month = DateTime.month
    day = DateTime.day
    return make_aware(datetime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I am afraid that if I call "make_aware" two times, I might offset the result. Did I do it right or not ? (my timezone is 'Europe/Paris')

PS : Feel free to criticize my code, I am a newbie developer

Comment: I'm not getting the exact requirement. how do you want to call your function and what's the expected output?

Comment: @xxbinxx I want to call my function in a billing app to bill on the right day. But if my function has a time offset, I might bill the wrong day : for example if a customer order something at 1 in the morning the 15/07/2019, in France but I have an offset of -2 hours the date calculated (difference between UTC and UTC+2 in France), my function would return the start of the day 14/07/2019 instead of the 15/07/2019 and it would be wrong in the customer's perspective. I wondered if my strategy to evade this case was right or not ?

Comment: you have your user's timezone saved in the database?

Comment: @xxbinxx No, should I ? I didn't thought of that. I only generate dates on the server side and I thought Django would deduce from the requests the right timezone to send, I m not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

def day_beginning(dt=None):
    # if dt is None, localtime() operates on now()
    return localtime(dt).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kevin Christopher Henry I was able to write a better function :

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

def DayBeginning(DateTime=None):
    if not DateTime :
        DateTime = make_aware(datetime.datetime.today())
    else :
        try :
            DateTime= make_aware(DateTime)
        except ValueError :
            pass
    return DateTime.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

I wanted to use make_aware to always use my server's timezone settings, I wasn't sure about localtime (if the server was not in the same country for example)

make_aware returns a ValueError if you give it a datetime which already have a timezone setting, that s the reason for the try/except.

Comment: Django's timezone handling is designed to *avoid* relying on the operating system's timezone, because that's almost always the wrong thing to do. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Ah maybe I don't understand the difference between make_aware and localtime. I see localtime is also a django's built-in module. Is make_aware for the server's timezone and localtime is for the user's timezone ?

Comment: Make sure to read the documentation as all of your questions are addressed there. An [aware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) datetime is just one with a timezone. [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) changes the timezone while keeping the moment in time the same. Django [can't figure out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) your users' time zones because nothing in the HTTP specification allows for that.